# Why are mobile friendly tests by Google and Bing incorrectly saying my site is not mobile friendly?

Tags: css, mobile

My resources site is responsive and has been tested on multiple real phones (iPhone, Android, Windows) and looks good on every phone we've tested it on.

The resources site: https://www.bidsketch.com/resources/

It also scales down fine when tested in Chrome and Safari. Yet, both Bing and Google mobile friendly tests don't see the site correctly.

It's almost like they're seeing the older cached version of the CSS, but they are seeing the meta/viewport tag. Though we've don't see how that could be cached being that the site is just serving the latest version and it's been weeks that we're experiencing this problem.

Our marketing site which has similar responsive code is correctly seen as responsive.

In the resources site the **marketing-31db0bf8ce9fcecf2bceb39be640285e.css** file has the responsive CSS code:

```
/**
 Responsive
 */
@media (max-width: 720px) {
    #header .logo {
        float: none !important;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    #header #nav {
        float: none !important;
        display: block;
    }
    #header #nav li {
        float: none !important;
    }

    #header {
        text-align: center;
        padding-right: 20px !important;
        padding-left: 20px !important;
    }

    .heading-box h1 {
        line-height: 140%;
    }

    .main-wrap {
        padding:0 20px;
    }

    #content.resources .tour-box {
        float: none !important;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    #content.resources .featured .browse-resources {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        display: inline-block;
    }


    .start-block .title {
        float: none !important;
        font-size: 20px !important;
        margin-bottom: 8px;
    }

    .start-block a.btn {
        margin-top:8px !important;
    }

    #footer {
        width: 100% !important;
    }

    .start-block {
        background: #074b54 !important;
        height: 140px !important;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .start-block a.btn {
        float: none !important;
        display: block;
        margin-right: auto !important;
        margin-left: auto !important;
    }

    #content.resources .tour-box {
        width: auto !important;
        max-width: 400px;
        float: none !important;
    }

    #content.resources .featured {
        padding: 80px 20px 20px 20px !important;
    }

    #content.resources .tour-block .visual {
        margin: 0 10px !important;
    }

    .tour-box .visual {
        float: none !important;
        width: auto !important;
        max-width: 300px;
    }

    .main-holder {
        overflow: visible !important;
    }

    .template-block {
        padding-right: 0px !important;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .resource-image {
        margin: 7px auto 0 !important;
    }

    .resource-form {
        margin-right: auto !important;
        float: none !important;
        width: auto !important;
        display: block !important;
    }

    h2.inline {
        max-width: 700px;
        width: auto !important;
    }

    .content-block {
        width: auto !important;
        max-width: 960px;
    }
    .content-block > div {
        max-width: 600px;
        width: auto !important;
        margin: 0 !important;
        padding: 0 20px;
    }

    p > iframe {
        width: 100% !important;
    }

    .template-area {
        overflow: visible !important;
    }

    #content {
        float: none !important;
        width: auto !important;
        max-width: 710px;
    }

    .tour-box {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .tour-box .visual {
        margin: 0 auto !important;
    }

    .heading-box {
        padding: 60px 10px 15px !important;
    }

    #sidebar {
        display: none;
    }

    #footer p, 
    #footer .social-nav, 
    #footer .logo-bottom { 
        display: none !important; 
    }

    #footer .bottom-nav li {
        float: none !important;
        background: none !important;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 200%;
        margin: 0 !important;
        padding: 0 !important;
    }
    .footer-holder { height: auto !important; }
    #footer .area { float: none !important; width: 100% !important; margin: 0 auto !important; }
    #footer { padding: 37px 0 !important; }
    #footer .bottom-nav li a {
        padding: 10px !important;
        display: block;
    }
} 


body .start-block .title {
    font-size: 24px;
}

#footer {
    max-width: 980px !important;
    width: auto !important;
}

body {
    min-width: auto !important;
}

#header {
    width: auto !important;
    max-width: 960px;
}

.main-wrap {
    width: auto !important;
    max-width: 960px;
}

#content.resources,
#content.resources .category-row {
    width: auto !important;
    max-width: 840px;
}

#content.resources .tour-block .summary {
    width: auto !important;
    max-width: 800px;
}

.start-block {
    width: auto !important;
    max-width: 916px;
}

.main-wrap .resources-intro {
    width: auto !important;
    max-width: 750px;
}

.template-block {
    width: auto !important;
    max-width: 940px;
}
```

Is there something we're not doing right or can change to make the resources site come up as mobile friendly like our marketing site is?

Comment: Could it be that you're using an XHTML 1 DTD and didn't self-close your meta viewport tag? You have a bunch of validation errors that probably don't matter to the average browser, but may to bots that scrape your page.

Comment: Doesn't seem likely because marketing site has exact same doctype and viewport tags (I just checked) and it works over there. Still, I went ahead and changed it to transitional and it still fails :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After wasting way too much time troubleshooting this, finally figured out what Google and Bing mobile tests didn't like.

The body tag had this style applied:

```
body {
    min-width: auto !important;
}
```

Changed it to this and it worked:

```
body {
    min-width: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely some of the elements are getting cut off on the right side and the whole content is pushed slightly to the right. Usually, when you run your website through these test you will get some kind of instructions or alerts. Weird, the first time I ran your site on https://search.google.com/search-console/mobile-friendly it showed two errors (buttons too close, and content out to the right). So, just in the case I ran it again and I see no error and it says that site is mobile friendly.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. Yeah, it's the container with the class "main-wrap" that Google doesn't seem to be following max-width and width: auto there. It's doing it correctly for the nav (I can see just enough of it to see that it's stacking those vertically), but not that main-wrap for some reason. I just checked and still not mobile friendly for me.